# antd-mobile ，using babel-plugin-import，Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, webpack, antd-mobile

"redux": "^4.0.0",
node : v10.2.1

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react"],
    "plugins": [
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime",
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        ["import", { "libraryName": "antd-mobile",  "style": "css"}] 
    ]
}
```

script:

```
import { Button } from "antd-mobile";
...
<Button type="primary">primary</Button>
...
```

then it comes :

```
invariant.js:42 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `Button`.
```

how can I fix it ?